# How to partially disable a Linux screen via grid selection

Tags: display

Let's say a user is running a program (for example a browser) on a 1920x1080 monitor but is only interested in columns 640-1919.

Hypothetically, this user suffers from epilepsy and has observed that the unholy flickering of certain advertisements in columns 0-639 occasionally triggers a fit.

Also hypothetically, this user feels environmental guilt over constantly and unnecessarily delivering electricity to 1/3 of the available (power-hungry) pixels.

Philosophically, this same user believes it a fundamental human right to have  absolute control over *what he wants to see* and wonders why the operating system does not allow him to **drag a virtual curtain** over any uninteresting screen region.

Does such a Linux extension already exist?

If not, where would someone with only Android/Java experience begin study?

Comment: you could start with arts and crafts classes ... learn how to cut out paper overlays for the screen so that you could cover the offending content

Comment: @jsotola No matter that the paper may once have been orangutan habitat?